# Delphi library for MIDI input/output?

Tags: delphi, midi

What is a good Delphi library for MIDI input/output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using these components for [ages](http://www.xs4all.nl/~niff/fs1r):

http://bitbucket.org/h4ndy/midiio-dev

They've hardly ever failed on me, and unlike many other specialized Delphi components that have been around for this long, this code is pretty much alive (updates and improvements added recently).

Nothing fancy, but it's easy to use, fast, and rock solid. If you plan to do serious midi stuff, you'll eventually end up using this.

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure that you really need a third-party library? If your needs are basic, the Windows API is all you need (`using MMSystem`).

```
var
  mo: HMIDIOUT;

const
  MIDI_NOTE_ON = $90;
  MIDI_NOTE_OFF = $80;
  MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT = $C0;
  MIDI_DEVICE = 0;
  MIDI_VEL = 108;

procedure MIDIInit;
begin
  midiOutOpen(@mo, MIDI_DEVICE, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
  SetPlaybackVolume($FFFFFFFF);
end;

function MIDIEncodeMessage(Msg, Param1, Param2: integer): integer;
begin
  result := Msg + (Param1 shl 8) + (Param2 shl 16);
end;

procedure SetCurrentInstrument(CurrentInstrument: TMIDIInstrument);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT, ord(CurrentInstrument), 0));
end;

procedure NoteOn(NewNote, NewIntensity: byte);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_NOTE_ON, NewNote, NewIntensity));
end;

procedure NoteOff(NewNote, NewIntensity: byte);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_NOTE_OFF, NewNote, NewIntensity));
end;

procedure SetPlaybackVolume(PlaybackVolume: cardinal);
begin
  midiOutSetVolume(mo, PlaybackVolume);
end;
```

where the instruments are

```
type
  TMIDIInstrument = (midiAcousticGrandPiano, midiBrightAcousticPiano,
                     midiElectricGrandPiano, midiHonkyTonkPiano,
                     midiRhodesPiano, midiChorusedPiano, midiHarpsichord,
                     midiClavinet, midiCelesta, midiGlockenspiel,
                     midiMusicBox, midiVibraphone, midiMarimba, midiXylophone,
                     midiTubularBells, midiDulcimer, midiHammondOrgan,
                     midiPercussiveOrgan, midiRockOrgan, midiChurchOrgan,
                     midiReedOrgan, midiAccordion, midiHarmonica,
                     midiTangoAccordion, midiAcousticGuitarNylon,
                     midiAcousticGuitarSteel, midiElectricGuitarJazz,
                     midiElectricGuitarClean, midiElectricGuitarMuted,
                     midiOverdrivenGuitar, midiDistortionGuitar,
                     midiGuitarHarmonics, midiAcousticBass, midiElectricBassFinger,
                     midiElectricBassPick, midiFretlessBass, midiSlapBass1,
                     midiSlapBass2, midiSynthBass1, midiSynthBass2, midiViolin,
                     midiViola, midiCello, midiContrabass, midiTremoloStrings,
                     midiPizzicatoStrings, midiOrchestralHarp, midiTimpani,
                     midiStringEnsemble1, midiStringEnsemble2, midiSynthStrings1,
                     midiSynthStrings2, midiChoirAahs, midiVoiceOohs,
                     midiSynthVoice, midiOrchestraHit, midiTrumpet, midiTrombone,
                     midiTuba, midiMutedTrumpet, midiFrenchHorn, midiBrassSection,
                     midiSynthBrass1, midiSynthBrass2, midiSopranoSax, midiAltoSax,
                     midiTenorSax, midiBaritoneSax, midiOboe, midiEnglishHorn,
                     midiBassoon, midiClarinet, midiPiccolo, midiFlute,
                     midiRecorder, midiPanFlute, midiBottleBlow, midiShakuhachi,
                     midiWhistle, midiOcarina, midiLead1Square,
                     midiLead2Sawtooth, midiLead3CalliopeLead, midiLead4ChiffLead,
                     midiLead5Charang, midiLead6Voice, midiLead7Fifths,
                     midiLead8BrassLead, midiPad1NewAge, midiPad2Warm,
                     midiPad3Polysynth, midiPad4Choir, midiPad5Bowed,
                     midiPad6Metallic, midiPad7Halo, midiPad8Sweep, midiEmpty0,
                     midiEmpty1, midiEmpty2, midiEmpty3, midiEmpty4, midiEmpty5,
                     midiEmpty6, midiEmpty7, midiEmpty8, midiEmpty9, midiEmpty10,
                     midiEmpty11, midiEmpty12, midiEmpty13, midiEmpty14,
                     midiEmpty15, midiEmpty16, midiEmpty17, midiEmpty18,
                     midiEmpty19, midiEmpty20, midiEmpty21, midiEmpty22,
                     midiEmpty23, midiGuitarFretNoise, midiBreathNoise,
                     midiSeashore, midiBirdTweet, midiTelephoneRing,
                     midiHelicopter, midiApplause, midiGunshot);
```

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MIDIInit;
  SetCurrentInstrument(midiHarmonica);
  NoteOn(50, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOn(60, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOn(70, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOff(70, 127);
  NoteOff(60, 127);
  NoteOff(50, 127);
  SetCurrentInstrument(midiAcousticGrandPiano);
  NoteOn(70, 127);
  NoteOn(80, 127);

  sleep(1000);
  SetCurrentInstrument(midiApplause);
  NoteOn(64, 127);
  sleep(2000);
  NoteOff(64, 127);
end;
```

Comment: Hello. I do not know how to make a question about this subject.. I test que code.. and if I try to put it into a buttonEvent.. it just work once.. how can I reSet it? make sound any time i want to? thanks

Comment: @Pericles Remove `MIDIInit` from your button; keep in on `FormCreate` event.

Answer (score 3):

I've used these components for over 6 months now with great success. They should be evaluated with all the others in the follow up posts.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/midisequencer/

Answer (score 2):

[DMIDI project webpage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dmidi)

Answer (score 2):

I have used [BASS MIDI](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22bass+midi%22+un4seen) using the .NET wrapper with great success, and there are [Delphi wrappers](http://www.google.com/search?q=BASSMIDI+delphi) available for it too.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple MIDI in/out class:
[www.midimountain.com/delphi_midi.html](http://www.midimountain.com/delphi_midi.html)

It looks like a good starting point if you would like to roll your own and use the windows API.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small extra info: The SourceForge "dmidi" project is actually the same as the "midiio" on BitBucket (but the development happens here).

Answer (score 1):

Mon 4/14/2014 9:49 am. Since I'm not allowed to comment, I'll try answering: I cast my living-in-the-past vote for the midimountain.com candidate. I got the demo_MidiDevices_D6.zip (get it on the page [http://www.midimountain.com/delphi_midi.html](http://www.midimountain.com/delphi%5fmidi.html), *not* the "download" link), unzipped it, and it compiled without incident in my antique Delphi 7 and *ran*. I haven't actually tested if it does MIDI, but it *did* show my menagerie of attached MIDI devices....